# retrieve and add two numbers of files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In my file I have following structure :-

```
A | 12 | 10
B | 90 | 112
C | 54 | 34
```

What I have to do is I have to add column 2 and column 3 and print the result with column 1.

output:-

```
A | 22
B | 202
C | 88
```

I retrieve the two columns but dont know how to add
What I did is :-
`cut -d ' | ' -f3,5 myfile.txt`
How to add those columns and display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with awk.

`awk '{print $1," | ",($3+$5)'} myfile.txt`
wil work perhaps.

Comment: I'd say `BEGIN{FS="|"}` and using `$1`, `$2` and `$3` would be more intuitive and more robust.

Answer (score 4):

A Bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="|" read f1 f2 f3
do
   echo $f1 "|" $((f2+f3))
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS="| "} {print $1 OFS $2+$3}' input_filename
```

**Input:**

```
A | 12 | 10
B | 90 | 112
C | 54 | 34
```

**Output:**

```
A | 22
B | 202
C | 88
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk`: invoke the `awk` tool
- `BEGIN{...}`: do things before starting to read lines from the file
- `FS="|"`: `FS` stands for Field Separator. Think of it as the delimiter that separates each line of your file into fields
- `OFS="| "`: `OFS` stands for Output Field Separator. Same idea as above, but for output. FS =/= OFS in this case due to formatting
- `{print $1 OFS $2+$3}`: For each line that `awk` reads, print the first field (the letter), followed by a delimiter specified by `OFS`, then the sum of field 2 and field 3.
- `input_filename`: awk accepts the input file name as an argument here.